# Linking two OptionMenu widgets Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two OptionMenu widgets in the simple pieces of code shown below:

```
    variable = StringVar(win1)                               
    variable.set(number(number2))
    type = OptionMenu(win1, variable, "None", "Clear", "Dark", "Heavy", )
    type.grid(row=i, column=3, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)


    variableunit = StringVar(win1)
    variableunit.set(unit)
    unit = OptionMenu(win1, variableunit, "colour", "shade")
    unit.grid(row=i, column=5, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
```

I have tried traces with a callback function and so far hasn't worked. I would like to link when "Heavy" is chosen in the first menu, the second menu is always "colour". For the rest of the choices, the second menu must always be a default of "shade" but can be changed.

I would be grateful is anyone could help me. I've already looked at the effbot site with variables and traces but am still stuck.

Comment: What do you mean with 'when "Load" is chosen in the "Heavy" in the first menu`? What's "Load"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you want, but I think this should do it.

When "Heavy" is selected in the first menu, "colour" is selected in the second one and that menu is disabled (can't select anything else). When something else is selected in the first menu, the second one goes to "mm" and is enabled again.

```
from Tkinter import *

class app:
    def __init__(self, root):
        win1 = Frame(root)
        win1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.variable = StringVar(win1)                               
        self.variable.set(42)
        self.type = OptionMenu(win1, self.variable,
                          "None", "Clear", "Dark", "Heavy",
                          command = self.varMenu)
        self.type.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)


        self.variableunit = StringVar(win1)
        self.variableunit.set('mm')
        self.unit = OptionMenu(win1,
                          self.variableunit, "mm", "colour", "shade")
        self.unit.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

    def varMenu(self, selection):
        if selection == "Heavy":
            self.variableunit.set("colour")
            self.unit.config(state = DISABLED)
        else:
            self.variableunit.set("mm")
            self.unit.config(state = NORMAL)

root = Tk()
a = app(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This work apart from the unit doesn't change to "colour" is stays as 'mm" and becomes disabled.

Comment: @user2063: Are you certain? Did you copy my code directly? It changes to 'colour' perfectly for me.

Comment: I didn't copy it directly but I've figured it out. Yet again a typo...! Thank you!