# Can you explain where does the variable selection came from in this solution

Tags: python, tkinter

This is an answer posted here:
[Linking two OptionMenu widgets Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097994/linking-two-optionmenu-widgets-tkinter)

I just want to know where did 'selection' come from in varmenu as we are not passsing anything in the command = self.varmenu

Thanks in advance

```
from Tkinter import *

class app:
    def __init__(self, root):
    win1 = Frame(root)
    win1.grid(row=0,column=0)

    self.variable = StringVar(win1)                               
    self.variable.set(42)
    self.type = OptionMenu(win1, self.variable,
                      "None", "Clear", "Dark", "Heavy",
                      command = self.varMenu)
    self.type.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)


    self.variableunit = StringVar(win1)
    self.variableunit.set('mm')
    self.unit = OptionMenu(win1,
                      self.variableunit, "mm", "colour", "shade")
    self.unit.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

def varMenu(self, selection):
    if selection == "Heavy":
        self.variableunit.set("colour")
        self.unit.config(state = DISABLED)
    else:
        self.variableunit.set("mm")
        self.unit.config(state = NORMAL)

root = Tk()
a = app(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're passing a *callback* to Tkinter, `selection` comes from the `OptionMenu` when *it* calls your callback method.

Comment: so when making optionsMenu i will have a selection variable that i can use for getting the selected entity in the options?

Comment: @Rishi No. When you make a selection in the `OptionMenu`, the `OptionMenu` calls the function you passed to it with `command=` and it will automatically pass the selected value as the first argument to that function. Therefore, the function that is called should accept one argument. What name you give to that argument is up to you.

Comment: @fhrsdg Thanks for the info.